# Настройка /etc/ufw/before.rules

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, ufw

настраиваю OpenVPN по этому гайду https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openvpn-ubuntu-16-04-ru

Столкнулся с проблемой, после включения в конфиг before.rules этого участка:

```
# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*NAT
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to eth0
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES
```

При последующей перезагрузке демона ufw, выводится следующая ошибка:

```
ERROR: problem running ufw-init
Bad argument `*NAT'
Error occurred at line: 21
```

Коллеги, кто может разъяснить, в чём проблема?

Comment: *NAT с маленькой там

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает

Answer (score 1):

Ответ [здесь](https://gist.github.com/kimus/9315140):

> What's actually going wrong is documented in this bug report:
>
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ufw/+bug/550976
>
> There's a missing 'COMMIT' for the filter table in the base ufw
>   config...
>
> Which means you've added your `*nat` section **after** the start of
>   the `*filters` section and you should move it to before the line
>   `*filter`

Answer (score 0):

После установки `DEFAULT_INPUT_POLICY="ACCEPT"` (по умолчанию `DROP`)
в  **/etc/default/ufw**, всё заработает.